# Как сделать в modx авторизацию на сайте по email или телефону

Tags: php, веб-программирование, modx

Я только начал знакомиться с MODX и тут надо сделать авторизацию на сайте. По гайду из документации (https://docs.modx.com/current/en/extras/login/login.tutorials/basic-setup) я смог сделать стандартную регистрацию и авторизацию. Но мне необходимо, чтобы пользователь авторизировался по Email или телефону, а не логину. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.modx.org/current/en/extras/login/login написано что можно использовать такой параметр loginViaEmail и ему указть true и будет логинится через профиль email но если он не уникальный то не авторизует

Comment: Спасибо, но это не совсем то, что надо. Я так понимаю, здесь речь идёт только про email. Мне ведь и по номеру телефона авторизоваться надо. Т.е. пользователь в одно поле вводит либо почту, либо номер, а во второе пароль. И заранее я не знаю что он введёт.

Comment: тогда надо посмотреть сторону хуков preHook которые предоставляет данный сниппет и попробовать там переопределить условия. Но на самом деле я помню в Register есть поле usernameField посмотрите может оно есть и в сниппете Login

Comment: О, я это поле знаю. Я его использовал на форме регистрации, чтобы сделать логин равным email`у. И похоже в логине аналогичного нет. Да и если бы было, разве можно сразу два значения в него впихнуть?

Comment: думаю здесь будет ваше решение проблемы https://modx.pro/help/5085

Comment: Разобрался что есть плагины и как использовать. Но не работает. Я что-то сделал не так?
$modx->event->_outputonUserNotFound  = $modx->getObjectGraph('modUser', '{"Profile":{},"UserSettings":{}}', array ('Profile.phone' => $scriptProperties['username']));